# Unity is saying my keystore password is wrong

Tags: unity-game-engine

yesterday I tried to use a keystore while building my game (to android). However, Unity always thinks that the password I inputted is wrong, even though I have made sure it is not. It could also be in the path, as Unity keeps saying

> Unable to create key in keystore. Please make sure the location and password of the keystore is correct.

So what do I do? I have been trying for hours and hours, so any input would be truly awesome.

Comment: Is the path correct? Which unity version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that it is and also, Unity autofills it, much to my confusion. I'm using version 2019.1.0a14.